Loss function in Isolation Forest
I have recently came across on this algorithm and was working on my graduation project.
As per my understanding, we creates sub trees for each sub samples. Then we calculates the scores for each datapoint using - 2^E(h(x))/c(n). But, I have two queries about isolation forest.

Unlike the other unsupervised learning algorithm i.e. K-means clustering where we use to minimizes the WCSS (within cluster sum of squares), What we actually minimizes in the isolation forest?

What is the optimization method to minimize such a loss function. How isolation forest minimize the loss while training the model?


I have gone through the Original Paper and was looking for an answer in other sources also but I could not find anything relevant.
Thanks in advance.

The scikit-learn User Guide has a section on their IsolationForest class. It's similar to a random forest, but where they track how many splits it takes (on average) to isolate each sample. Samples isolated in just a few splits are considered outliers.

Since Isolation Forest is an unsupervised anomaly detection algorithm, it does not explicitly minimize a loss function. It randomly partitions the feature space to isolate anomalies. Anomalies tend to have shorter path lengths in the individual Isolation Trees.
Since there is no explicit loss function, it is not helpful to look for an optimization method. A more useful framing might be thinking of it as a construction algorithm. The isolation forest is created by recursively partitioning the feature space to create an ensemble of Isolation Trees.
There are two steps to the the construction of a Isolation Forest:

First, construct Isolation Trees:

Randomly select a feature and a split value.
Split the data based on the selected feature and split value.
Repeat the process recursively until all instances are isolated in their own separate partition or a maximum tree depth is reached.


Second, calculate an anomaly score for an instance based on the average path length across all trees. Instances with shorter average path lengths are considered more anomalous.


Thanks for the explanation. But, I still have a small query. If there is no loss function then how isolation forest make sure that the anomaly detected by isolation trees is actually the 'anomaly'. It could be possible that instance is not anomaly but it is wrongly captured as 'anomaly' by isolation trees. Like in K-means clustering we make sure that WCSS for each cluster should be small as possible. Is there any evaluation metrices available for isolation trees?

iForest algorithm from what I can understand from the paper is used for anomaly detection and doesn't have a traditional loss function. It isolates anomalies by constructing an ensemble of Isolation Trees (iTrees). Each tree is built by randomly selecting a feature and a split value, then recursively partitioning the data. Anomalies tend to be isolated quickly, resulting in shorter path lengths in the trees.
